# Trying to write a shell script to monitor when a service stops in linux, and to automate the restart of this service

Tags: linux, centos, centos6, process-monitoring

So I am relatively new to Centos, version 6.2. I have a service that needs to be mnonitored as a cron job, and if it stops needs to be restarted. I have a few ideas on how to monitor it, but when it comes to getting it restarted thats when I get stuck. I also know the PiD of the service I want to monitor.

Comment: Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `supervise` for this: http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/supervise.html

Put it in your crontab to launch on system start:

```
@reboot supervise foo
```

Comment: Sorry I suppose I should have clarified. I am required to only do it through bash scripting. So no convenient or easy to use tools, otherwise I would be using daemon tools

Comment: Well then it's time to start writing code.  We won't do it for you.